# Get the max value and join the text from the data frame, using groupby(), value_counts(), join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group the date and count the same item in the each day and then I want to get max value of count and join the item.
My data frame is like this.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-09-10','2020-09-10','2020-09-10','2020-09-10','2020-09-08','2020-09-08'],
                   'fruit':['apple','banana','apple','oragne','apple','orange'], 
                   'value':['1','1','2','3','3','3']})
input:
x = df.groupby('date')['value'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index().drop_duplicates('date')

output:
         date value  count
0  2020-09-08     3      2
1  2020-09-10     1      2

input :
df.groupby(['date', 'value'])['fruit'].apply(' '.join)

output:
date        value
2020-09-08  3        apple orange
2020-09-10  1        apple banana
            2               apple
            3              oragne
```

My expected output is :

```
output:
         date value  count  fruit
0  2020-09-08     3      2  apple orange
1  2020-09-10     1      2  apple banana
```

Comment: why do you have `orange` in the output for `2020-09-10`?

Comment: Sorry, this is my false. it will apple orange and apple banana.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to get the rows with the maximum number of items that share the same date/value.

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
out = (
 df.groupby(['date', 'value'], as_index=False)['fruit']
   .agg(**{'count': 'count', 'fruit': ' '.join})
   .loc[lambda d: d.groupby('date')['count'].idxmax()]
)
```

Or, if you can have several max counts per date and want to keep all:

```
out = (
 df.groupby(['date', 'value'], as_index=False)['fruit']
   .agg(**{'count': 'count', 'fruit': ' '.join})
   .loc[lambda d: d.groupby('date')['count'].transform('max').eq(d['count'])]
)
```

Or building on your existing code with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# simplification of the way to compute "x"
# you could also use your original code
x = df[['date', 'value']].value_counts().reset_index().drop_duplicates('date')

out = x.merge(df.groupby(['date', 'value'], as_index=False)
              ['fruit'].agg(' '.join), how='left')
```

*NB. like my first code, this approach would only keep the first max count even if there are several maxes per date.*

Output:

```
         date value  count         fruit
0  2020-09-08     3      2  apple orange
1  2020-09-10     1      2  apple banana
```